# awkの効率的プログラム

Tags: windows, awk

Windows10のコマンドプロンプトでgawk5を使っています。

ファイルが ss1.txt から ss10.txt の１０個あり、対応するawkプログラムも fff1.awk から fff10.awkまで10個あります。

これらをバッチファイルで実行すると10行になります。

```
gawk -b -f fff1.awk ss1.txt
gawk -b -f fff2.awk ss2.txt
gawk -b -f fff3.awk ss3.txt
　↓　（中間省略）
gawk -b -f fff10.awk ss10.txt
```

これをコンパクトにまとめたいので、下記の test.awkを作成してみたが、gawk から system関数で 子gawk を起動するので、遅く非効率と考えています。

test.awk

```
BEGIN{
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
cmd="gawk -b -f fff" i ".awk " "ss" i ".txt"
system(cmd)
close(cmd)
}
}
```

system関数やgawkを二重に起動したりしない方法がうまく作成できません。
何か良い方法をアドバイスください。お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

バッチファイルならば

```
FOR /L %I IN (1,1,10) DO gawk -b -f fff%I.awk ss%I.txt
```

PowerShellならば

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
  gawk -b -f fff$i.awk ss$i.txt
}
```

とかでしょうか。

---

本質的にはawkプログラムを１つに集約するか、別言語に切り替えることをお勧めします。

Comment: 教えていただいた２つの方法は、速度が遅くなることも無さそうです。参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

コマンドプロンプトではなく、WSL2 環境が利用できるのであれば以下の様になります。興味がありましたら試してみて下さい。

```bash
$ seq 10 | xargs -P0 -I@ gawk -b -f fff@.awk ss@.txt
```

Comment: xargsは縦のリストを横にするくらいしか使っていませんでした。便利な使い方があるんですね。ありがとうございました。